# Why does the definition of MyAnnotation need Documented, Inherited, Retention & RetentionPolicy?

Tags: java, annotations

What is the purpose of these `java.lang.annotation` imports in this code? Why are they needed to define MyAnnotation?

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface MyAnnotation {
  String value() default "";
}
```

Comment: Look http://stackoverflow.com/a/20432882/715269 for explanation of Documented and Inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Documented and @Inherited are not required. @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) is only needed if you want to process the annotations in the runtime.