# @Documented annotation in java

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

What's the purpose of `@Documented` annotation in java?

I saw the documentation, but could not get much from it. Can someone point out with the help of an clear example

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`@Documented` is a meta-annotation. You apply `@Documented` when defining an annotation, to ensure that classes using your annotation show this in their generated JavaDoc. I've not seen much use of it, but [there is an example here](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/10936_3556176_3/An-Introduction-to-Java-Annotations.htm). An earlier question suggests that it [doesn't work automatically in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821758/does-eclipse-not-show-documented-parameter-annotations), but I've tested in Eclipse 3.6, and my annotations appear in the JavaDoc popups whether or not I attach the `@Documented` annotation to them.

Here's an example from Spring, which ensures that transactional methods are marked as such in the JavaDoc:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface Transactional {
```

Answer (score 52):

If some our annotation (for example, `@InWork`) is `@Documented`, then for every class having that `@InWork` annotation the text generated by javadoc will contain `@InWork` text, as a reference to the annotation.

Annotation:

```
@Documented
@Inherited  // for descenders of the annotation to have the @Documented feature automatically
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) // must be there
public @interface InWork {
    String value();
}
```

Annotated target:

```
/**
 * Annotated class.
 */
@InWork(value = "")
public class MainApp {...}
```

The javadoc text:

[image]

So, you have to decide, if the annotation should be shown in the javadoc text, and if yes, set `@Documented` to it.

The information above is taken from [Oracle documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/hunter-meta-2-098036.html).

---

*Please, notice, that in Eclipse you'll see in javadoc generated text ALL annotations, are they `@Documented`, or not.*

It is still correct for 4.3 version.

Answer (score 5):

I found a useful page in the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html) which gives examples and more explanation for a number of standard annotations, including one use of `@Documented`. Specifically, look at the **Note** block at the bottom for the Preamble example ([section Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html)).